# Haskell: negate a value of type Ordering

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to negate or invert a value of type Ordering? Something like this:

```
inv = not compare
```

Comment: An `Ordering` has three values `LT`, `GT` and `EQ`, so that would mean that the negation of `LT` is `GT` **or** `EQ`, but we can not represent such union as an `Ordering`.

Comment: So it is not possible to make `LT` into `GT`, `GT` into `LT`, leaving `EQ` intact, all in one operation?

Comment: Sure that is possible, but it makes no sense that `EQ = not EQ`...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are getting the Ordering from `compare`, then you can change
it to `flip compare`:

```
> flip compare 3 4
GT
```

Or you can wrap the values in `Down` from `Data.Ord`, a newtype that
exists to reverse the ordering of things:

```
> compare (Down 3) (Down 4)
GT
```

If you can't or don't want to change the place that the Ordering comes
from, you'll need a function to invert it and I don't know of a
built-in one.  You can write the obvious pattern match, or since
Ordering is itself ordered:

```
inv :: Ordering -> Ordering
inv = compare EQ
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is contained in Data.Ord and is a type called `Down`.

I cite:

> "If a has an Ord instance associated with it then comparing two values
>   thus wrapped will give you the opposite of their normal sort order."

Reference: 
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Ord.html